# ReactJs - Pass a utilitarian function to a paragraph inside of a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a utilitarian funcion `noMoreLonelyWords()` that renders a text avoiding a single word in the end of line. Everything is working good when I import and use this function in a component. The problem is this funcion isn't rendering the paragraph inside the modal. How can I solve it?

**React Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal';
import { noMoreLonelyWords } from './utilities/utilities.js';

class PortfolioPage extends Component {
    componentDidUpdate() {
        noMoreLonelyWords("p", 2)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Modal>
                <p>My text here!</p>
            </Modal>
        )

    }
}

export default PortfolioPage
```

**noMoreLonelyWords function:**
**Note:** This function is working good. The body of this function doesn't matter. It could be anything that change the paragraph. The goal is apply it into the Modal and modify its paragraph.

```
export const noMoreLonelyWords = (selector, numWords) => {      
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) { 
      var textArray = elems[i].innerText.split(" ");      
      var lastWords = textArray.splice(-numWords, numWords).join("&nbsp;");     
      var textMinusLastWords = textArray.join(" ");
      elems[i].innerHTML = textMinusLastWords + " " + lastWords;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you show code of `noMoreLonelyWords ` function?

Comment: Yes but this function is workin good.

Comment: 1. You need to display your modal, it's hidden by default. 2. I don't see your your function mutating state, you are passing it one character and a number what does it do? https://react-responsive-modal.leopradel.com/

Comment: ok I will edit the question with the function noMoreLonelyWords

Comment: what do `noMoreLonelyWords() function` do with this component `PortfolioPage `?

Comment: renders a text avoiding a single word in the end of line. It is userful for long paragraphs.

Comment: You are mutating the dom outside the React state machine, which makes little sense. Also, How does this algorithm know that there is only one word on the last line? What if there's two words? And you remove one leaving another one?

Comment: The funcion goal doesn't matter could be anything to be inserted into the modal and transform its paragraph.

Comment: Hi @claudiobitar! I hope you found my answer sufficient for what you're trying to accomplish. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AvinKavish has mentioned, using `componentDidMount()` will not be effective in persisting the appearance of your component.

You're also forcefully manipulating the DOM by changing the `innerHTML` of your selectors. This is very anti-pattern and defeats the purpose of using React.

Let's say you wanted to make your component more complex. You might update the `state` of `PortfolioPage` by adding a new item, or you are connected to `redux` and you initialize some sort of `action` that brings in new `props` to your component. Your component will re-render itself with the new data, and it will revert back to its initial state, making everything that happened in `componentDidMount()` useless. `componentDidMount()` will not execute a second time.

Also I'm sure you probably find it weird to call `noMoreLonelyWords` **after** the component has already mounted. That would mean, the paragraphs were already displayed on the screen and then they shift erratically to fit inside your modal.

What you really should be doing is calling `noMoreLonelyWords` at the time of `render`, so your paragraphs are already adjusted correctly by the time the user sees your component.

To fix this, you should update `noMoreLonelyWords()`, instead of passing in the selector to update, just pass in the text itself.

```
export const noMoreLonelyWords = (words, numWords) => {
  var textArray = words.split(" ");
  var lastWords = textArray.splice(-numWords, numWords).join("\xa0");
  var textMinusLastWords = textArray.join(" ");
  var newLine = textMinusLastWords + " " + lastWords;
  return newLine;
};
```

This preserves a lot of the logic that you already wrote and will also not affect other elements outside of your component, which is what you are doing when you call `document.querySelectorAll` to get **everything** on the page and manipulate it.

Now we can bring in your updated `noMoreLonelyWords()` and use it by passing in any body of text you want to configure.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Modal from "react-responsive-modal";
import { noMoreLonelyWords } from "./utilities/utilities.js";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class PortfolioPage extends Component {
  state = {
    openModal: false
  };

  handleModal = () => {
    this.setState({
      openModal: !this.state.openModal
    });
  };

  createParagraphs = (paragraph, minWordsPerLine) => {
    return <p>{noMoreLonelyWords(paragraph, minWordsPerLine)}</p>;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.createParagraphs(
          "Hello friend. October arrived, spreading a damp chill over the grounds and into the castle. Madam Pomfrey, the nurse, was kept busy by a sudden spate of colds among the staff and students. Her Pepperup potion worked instantly, though it left the drinker smoking at the ears for several hours afterward. Ginny Weasley, who had been looking pale, was bullied into taking some by Percy. The steam pouring from under her vivid hair gave the impression that her whole head was on fire.",
          5
        )}
        <Modal open={this.state.openModal} onClose={this.handleModal}>
          <div>
            {this.createParagraphs(
              "Hello friend. October arrived, spreading a damp chill over the grounds and into the castle. Madam Pomfrey, the nurse, was kept busy by a sudden spate of colds among the staff and students. Her Pepperup potion worked instantly, though it left the drinker smoking at the ears for several hours afterward. Ginny Weasley, who had been looking pale, was bullied into taking some by Percy. The steam pouring from under her vivid hair gave the impression that her whole head was on fire.",
              15
            )}
          </div>
        </Modal>
        <button onClick={this.handleModal}>Open Modal</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the above we've defined a function called `createParagraphs()`. It accepts two arguments, a body of text and a **number** for the minimum count of words that are allowed to be on a line. It will call`noMoreLonelyWords()` and inject the output inside a `<p></p>`.

See it in action here: https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-setting-minimum-words-per-line-hy7bc

We will use this function twice:

1. Outside the Modal we call `createParagraphs()` pass in some text,
   and set the minimum count to 5. Now you see the last line has 5
   words as we expected.
2. Inside the Modal we call `createParagraphs()` pass in the same text,
   and set the requirement to 15. Now the modal has 15 words in the
   last line.

Answer (score 2):

No action to change state. So `componentDidUpdate()` never called.

```
componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.
```

That is docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

You should use `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount(){
    noMoreLonelyWords("p", 2)
}
```

Comment: This will not work as the mutations you have made in DidMount will get overridden by the next render cycle. Initially it will appear to work but the changes will not persist. It'll lead to programs that are hard to reason and behave erratically and defeat the purpose of using React in itself.

Comment: I agree with @AvinKavish. This is very anti-pattern for React. The problem isn't with Ryan's solution, moreso that the function should be reworked so it doesn't manipulate with the DOM in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest applying your function to the text itself instead of querying the dom directly. That's not good practice especially considering the effect of the function can be achieved without direct DOM manipulation. The reason you are accessing the DOM is to get the text of a paragraph but you don't need to as you already have that text in the render function.

```
  render() {
  return (
    <Modal>
      <h2><p>{noMoreLonelyWords('My text here!', 2)}</p></h2>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Comment: I know about it. I only wrote the code that have to do with the problem.